# How to display time according to country timezone

Tags: php, time

When I access my website which is hosted in USA and I'm viewing it from Pakistan, It actually shows me USA time and date,

Answer (score 2):

You can set your timezone with [date-default-timezone-set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) function.

Answer (score 1):

You may create function DisplayDate($datetoconvert) for your script to convert time to your time - and to return new time.

```
DisplayDate($xtime) //assuming its a unix timestamp..
{
$mydifferece = 6; // hours

$newtime = $xtime+($mydifference*3600); //
$newtime = date("d-m-Y H:i:s", $newtime);

return $newtime;

}
```

//html

Written by: '.DisplayDate($timewritten).';

**Function time for all users..**

- "session" table should now have "timezone" column - for users to enter their timezone, varchar(3) default nothing
- and we should have "select" options with timezones!

//lets display actual time to users..

```
//$xtime is database entry to be converted (if any)

//$usertimezone is a selected timezone by user, driven from session (guests) - or users table.. (ie +6, or -7, or +1 and so on..)


       DisplayDate($xtime="",$usertimezone="") 
        {
          if(!$xtime) //given time (to be converted) dont exists, okay - lets give some right now time..
          {
          $xtime = time(); //set time to "right now", unix timestamp
          }

         //now we have time, lets see if user selected his timezone..
         if($usertimezone != "") //someone selected his timezone, time to do the job..
         {  
//herein (additionally) we should add support for winter and summer time (daylight) - if that zone support that changes.. but im leaving that empty for now..

         $xtime = $xtime+($usertimezone*3600); //difference * seconds per hour
         }
         else
         {
         //usertimezone not set, user dont care about his time to be displayed correctly, or its just a bot or spider, so do nothing..
         }

         $xtime = date("j. m, Y. H:i:s", $xtime); //lets just do some cosmetics..

         return $xtime;
    }
```

// HTML

//from database - ie for displaying comments, or articles datecreated times..

```
echo DisplayDate($comment['commentdate'],$session['usertimezone']);
```

//to display clock lets say..

```
echo DisplayDate('',$session['usertimezone']);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I got the point, ok just for one country the problem may occur again if any one in china accesses my website and time is shown according to the difference, I think you got the point, do i need to write differences for every country ??? Please rep

Comment: You must allow to (EVERY) user to your website to enter its timezone via "select" dropdown. And that includes you. I re-edited function a bit for that scope.

Answer (score 0):

Store dates in UTC timezone, store the user's timezone preference in their profile, then display dates to that user in their preferred timezone.

```
<?php

// assume these preferences came from a database as-is
$userTimezonePreference = 'America/Denver';
$storedDateTimeAsUtc    = '2012-04-02 06:15:40';
$dateTime               = new DateTime($storedDateTimeAsUtc, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

echo 'ORIG: ', $dateTime->format(DateTime::RFC2822), PHP_EOL;
$dateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($userTimezonePreference));
echo 'USER: ', $dateTime->format(DateTime::RFC2822), PHP_EOL;
```